# Database Design : Is it a good idea to combine two tables with the same columns and too many data?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design

I have two table with the same columns,one is use to save bank's amount and the other to save cashdesk,they both might have many data,so i'm concerned about data retrieving speed.I don't know it's better to combine them by adding extra column to determine type of each record or create a separate table for each one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory you have one unique entity, So you need to consider one table to your accounts and another one for your types of accounts, for better performance you could separate these types of account on two different file groups and partitions and create an index on the typeFK for account table, in this scenario you have logically one entity that is ruled by relational theory and physically your data is separated and data retrieval process would be fast and beneficial.

Answer (score 6):

The main question you should be asking is - how am I querying the tables.
If there is no real logical connection between the 2 tables (you don't want to get the rows in the same query) - use 2 different tables, since the other why around you will need to hold another column to tell you what type of row you are working on, and that will slow you down and make your queries more complex

In addition FKs might be a problem if the same column if a FK to 2 different places

In addition (2nd) - locks might be an issue - if you work on one type you might block the other

conclusion - 2 tables, not just for speed